# Can't install pygame on python 3.8.3

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.8

I am on the latest version of python and I have tried all the commands to install **pyjama**, but the error I get is:

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
>   Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (1.9.6)

I don't know where to find this information or how to downgrade to a older version of python.

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

could you provide the commands you used for installation which results in that error?

Seems like you've already installed it on Python2 and are trying to install it there again. If you're using pip, maybe you could try using pip3 instead. Alternatively you can also use the following command:

> python3 -m pip install XXX

Comment: Yes I believe I did install it on python2 but then I went to python3. I have used the commands..

Comment: .. pip install pygame.     pip3 install pygame.   python3 -m install pygame